# put link on table row or any other way to put link

Tags: php, html

i have one php code for button creation

```
            for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
    {
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['btn_color']==1)
    $btbg="side-button5.png";
    if($row['btn_color']==2)
    $btbg="side-button6.png";
    if($row['btn_color']==3)
     $btbg="side-button7.png";
    if($row['btn_color']==4)
    ?>
            <br>
             <table width="200" height="50" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
             <td background="images/<?php echo $btbg ; ?>" style="background-repeat:no-repeat"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
              <td height="66">
              <div align="center" class="buttonside">
              <p>
    <a  class="buttonside" href="vpa.php?pgid=<?php echo $row['page_id']; ?>">
     <?php echo $row['btn_text']?></p>
              </a>
                                  </div>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                       <?php
                       }
                       ?>
```

this code is working fine but the link is on text, i want to put link on full button(background)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the button 'linkable', you'll need to wrap the `<a>` tag around it.

However, you're going to need to change your HTML markup structure - you can't wrap an anchor around a table cell!